# Changing text using css in smooth writing animated style

Tags: html, css, animation, text

I have created an animation using css to write the text in smooth writing style. I need help in changing the text with different one in similar way

**HTML & CSS**

````
.typed-out{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: 
    typing 1s forwards;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  width: 0;
}
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}
</style>
<h1>I'm Mumin, I'm a</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="typed-out">Web Developer</div></div>```
}
````

Answer (score 0):

i prefer you for you using javascript. which is easy to implement and understand.

```js
      var characterContainer = "WEBDEVELOPER".split("");
      var characterContainerLength = characterContainer.length;
      var charIndex = 0;
      function writeTheChars()
      {
            if (charIndex == characterContainerLength) {
                charIndex = 0;
                document.getElementById("webdevloper").innerHTML="";
                setTimeout(() => {
                //sleep the function for 500 milisecond
                 writeTheChars();
                }, 500); 
            }

            else
            {
                document.getElementById("webdevloper").innerHTML+=characterContainer[charIndex];
                charIndex++;
                setTimeout(writeTheChars, 90);
            }
            
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="writeTheChars()">
 <center><p style="color: red; font-size:30px" id="webdevloper"></p></center> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

And i guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Actually I want to display other text for example if it shows web developer then it should show some other text like ui ux designer using smooth typewriting effect same as my code does above. It there's anyway please assist. Thanks again